# Relating coefficients: partial derivative of ratio vs. ratio of partial derivatives, with logs

Tags: regression-coefficients, logarithm, derivative

Consider the following regression:
$$y_{ij}=\beta_a \times \log(A_{ij}) + \beta_b \times \log(B_{j}) + \tau_j + \mu_{ij}$$
where y, A and B are variables that vary at the $ij$ and $j$ levels respectively, $\beta_a$ and $\beta_b$ are parameters and $\tau_j$ are $j$-specific fixed effects and $\mu_{ij}$ is an iid error. The goal is to identify $\epsilon \equiv \frac{\beta_a}{\beta_b}$. However, due to $\tau_j$, $\beta_b$ is not identified, and $\tau_j$ must be included in the model because of concerns for correlation between $B_j$ and unobservable $j$-level variation (which would then bias estimates of $\beta_b$ if not controlled for with the fixed effects).

Instead I can run the three following regressions:
$$
(1) \,\, y_{ij}=\beta_{a1} \times \log(A_{ij}) + \tau_j + \mu^1_{ij} \\
(2) \,\, y_{ij}=\beta_{a2} \times \log(A_{ij}) + \gamma \times \log(\frac{A_{ij}}{B_j}) + \tau_j + \mu^2_{ij} \\
(3) \,\, y_{ij}=\beta_{a3} \times \log(A_{ij}) + \delta \times \frac{\log(A_{ij})}{\log(B_{j})} + \tau_j + \mu^3_{ij}
$$

Now is there a way to express $\beta_b$ as a function of the parameters I can identify $(\beta_{a1}, \beta_{a2}, \beta_{a3}, \gamma, \delta$)?

Comment: What do you mean by "relate"?  You can always do the calculations with the parameter estimates if you want estimates of the transformed parameters...

Comment: I mean, for example,  to express $\gamma$ as a function of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$. Essentially in my setting, I can identify the latter two parameters but not the first and thus would like to back it out from the two estimates I do have.

Comment: Is this just math or is it related to probability & statistics?  If the former, the math stackexchange site is likely a better fit...

Comment: @jbowman This isn't math, because the expressions involving "$\partial$" neither have standard mathematical definitions nor do they seem to have any inherent meaning.  km5041, could you please explain what you intend them to mean?

Comment: Apologies. Given the structure of my data and experiments, I can identify $\beta_a$, $\delta$, and $\epsilon$ via regression (theyre coefficients) and am trying to find a way to express $\beta_b$ as a function of some/all of those three parameters because my ultimate goal is to estimate $\gamma$.

Comment: Why not just run your regression to get estimates of the two $\beta$s and take the ratio of the estimates?

Comment: @jbowman because the nature of the experiment requires introducing fixed effects that prevent direct identification of one $\beta$. Hence my attempt at this indirect approach. But this does mean that I have estimates for $\beta_b$, $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ so if these three can somehow be arranged to solve for $\beta_a$ I’ll then have the ultimate goal of $\gamma$.

Comment: @whuber I've re-written the question to clarify my objectives per the identification constraints in the above comment.

Comment: The problem is that your apparent partial derivatives are not defined.  This notation makes sense for a single coordinate  in the context of a coordinate system, but a partial with respect to some combination of coordinates has no meaning (because it isn't clear which coordinates are "held constant" for the partial differentiation).

Comment: @whuber I can recover the two partial derivatives shown via regressions of y on the transformed versions of $A$ and $B$ ($\frac{\log(A)}{\log(B)}$ and $\log(\frac{A}{B})$). I am stuck with exactly the issue you raised about how its unclear what is constant - which is why I am wondering if the fact that I can identify one of the focal parameters (here $\beta_a$) and these two additional parameters can permit me to identify the second focal parameter ($\beta_b$) by writing it as an expression of the three parameters I do have.

Comment: In other words, I'm looking for a function $f()$, where $\beta_b = f(\beta_b \,,\, \frac{\partial y}{\partial \frac{\log(A)}{\log(B)}} \,,\, \frac{\partial y}{\partial \log(\frac{A}{B})})$. Although it may not be that both the second and third parameters are both necessary to define $f$

Comment: Since the notation is meaningless, the only thing we currently have to go on for understanding your question is your reference to "$\left(\frac{\log(A)}{\log(B)}, \log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)\right)$". Are you trying to perform a multiple regression of $y$ against those two new variables simultaneously?  Are you including $\log(A)$ and $\log(B)$ in that regression or not?

Comment: You should write out the function you are actually estimating, not the (irrelevant) one you aren't estimating, and then write the transforms of the parameters of the function you are actually estimating to the parameters you want to estimate.  This would make things much clearer.

Comment: @whuber question edited to be as specific as possible in what's going on. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: No problem. You refer to "$\delta_j$", but I don't see it anywhere. Why do you include $\tau_j$ at all? By using it, you leave $\beta_j$ undefined, which makes the problem insoluble--we have no way to characterize what it should be. Note, too, that any meaning that a coefficient like $\beta_j$ might have in a regression model is in the context of the other variables: the coefficient of the same variable, when other variables are included (or excluded), has a different meaning. These considerations suggest backing off from statistical formalism and instead stating your *scientific* questions.

Comment: @whuber $\delta_j$ was a typo - question edited again, and to also reflect the need for the fixed effects. I am concerned about correlation between unobservable $j$-level variation (which can only be controlled for with fixed effects) and $B_{j}$ (which I observe). I understand how coefficients on each variable are only interpretable within the context of the other variables and parameters also included in the model - which is why I'm hoping to find a relationship between the models I can identify to back out the parameter of interest ($\beta_b$), or at least an approximation. Is that clear?